# Elasticsearch terms aggregation on a not analyzed field with filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `not analyzed` field on my index:

```
"city": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
```

I have an aggregation like the following:

```
"aggs": {
    "city": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "city"
        }
    }
}
```

that gives me an output like this:

```
"aggregations": {
    "city": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 51,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 12478,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "New York",
                "doc_count": 28420
            },
            {
                "key": "London",
                "doc_count": 23456
            },
            {
                "key": "São Paulo",
                "doc_count": 12727
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to add a `match_phrase_prefix` query before processing the aggregation to filter my results based on a user text, like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "city": "sao"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "city": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "city"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and the result is... nothing!

```
"aggregations": {
    "city": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": []
    }
}
```

I was expecting an aggregation result on `São Paulo` city. Obviously the problem is that my field should have `lowercase` and `asciifolding` filters to have a match (São/sao), but I can't make my field analyzed because I don't want to have aggregation results like `São`, `Paulo`, `New`, `York` (that's what happens on analyzed fields).

What can I do? I tried a lot of combinations with mapping/query/aggs but I can't get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is `not_analyzed` the query terms are `case-sensitive`.
You could use [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) mapping on `city` with `analyzed and non-analyzed fields`.

Example:

```
put <index>/<type>/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "city": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

post <index>/<type>/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "city": "Sao"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "city": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "city.raw"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The field must match "sao" (lowercase and asciifolding) *AND* my aggs must return buckets like "São Paulo" and not "São" and "Paulo".

Comment: you would need to use `multi fields`  see the edited answer

Comment: Its not working at first at least in my case, when you'd put that mapping than after execute post query. But its working now when i executed post query this morning and i guess we need to do restart elastic service after applied that mapping issue. I dont know maybe we dont. Thanks a lot @keety

Comment: This [ES documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/aggregations-and-analysis.html) seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
"city": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
```

- "city" now is analyzed
- "city.keyword" is not analyzed